# JS script to allow front-end users to change the number values in the given table using the prompt

Tags: javascript

I am running a web application with a price table that would allow front-end users to bulk add the distribution markup to the items prices and then select a different currency by clicking the appropriate buttons and entering the value in the prompt. The values entered should appear on the buttons, after which it prevents any user interaction with the table. It also takes care of some details such as decimal separators and currency symbols in the table headers.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("markup-percent-button").addEventListener("click", setMarkupPercent);
    document.getElementById("currency-usd-button").addEventListener("click", setCurrencyRateUsd);
    document.getElementById("currency-eur-button").addEventListener("click", setCurrencyRateEur);
    window.currency = 'uyu';
}

function setMarkupPercent() {
    let markup = prompt('Enter the markup %', '20');
    if (markup == null) {
        return;
    } else if (isNaN(parseFloat(markup))) {
        alert('Input error.');
        return;
    } else {
        markup = parseFloat(markup);
        let markupPercentButton = document.getElementById('markup-percent-button');
        let interactiveElements = document.getElementsByClassName("table-controls")[0];
        markupPercentButton.firstElementChild.innerText = 'The markup is: +' + markup + '%';
        markupPercentButton.setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.5; color: blueviolet;");
        interactiveElements.setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.5;");
        let costsTableData = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        let costsHtmlArray = costsTableData.getElementsByClassName('numdata');
        let distributionPriceString, currentItemCost;
        for (let i = 0; i < costsHtmlArray.length; i++) {
            currentItemCost = parseFloat(costsHtmlArray[i].innerText.replace(',', '.'));
            if (window.currency == 'uyu') {
                distributionPriceString = (currentItemCost * (markup / 100 + 1)).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
            } else {
                distributionPriceString = (currentItemCost * (markup / 100 + 1)).toFixed(2);
            }
            costsHtmlArray[i].innerText = distributionPriceString;
        }
    }
}

function setCurrencyRateUsd() {
    let rateMultiplier = prompt('Enter the exchange multiplier for USD', '38.5');
    if (rateMultiplier == null) {
        return;
    } else if (isNaN(parseFloat(rateMultiplier))) {
        alert('Input error.');
        return;
    } else {
        window.currency = 'usd';
        let currencyUsdButton = document.getElementById('currency-usd-button');
        let currencyEurButton = document.getElementById('currency-eur-button');
        let interactiveElements = document.getElementsByClassName("table-controls")[0];
        currencyUsdButton.setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.5; color: blueviolet;");
        currencyEurButton.setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.35;");
        interactiveElements.setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.5;");
        rateMultiplier = parseFloat(rateMultiplier);
        currencyUsdButton.firstElementChild.innerText = '1 USD = ' + rateMultiplier + ' UYU';
        let costsTableData = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        let costsHtmlArray = costsTableData.getElementsByClassName('numdata');
        let usdPriceString, currentItemCost;
        for (let i = 0; i < costsHtmlArray.length; i++) {
            currentItemCost = parseFloat(costsHtmlArray[i].innerText.replace(',', '.'));
            usdPriceString = (currentItemCost / rateMultiplier).toFixed(2);
            costsHtmlArray[i].innerText = usdPriceString;
        }
        let costsHeadersData = document.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0];
        let headersHtmlArray = costsHeadersData.getElementsByClassName('numdata');
        for (let y = 0; y < headersHtmlArray.length; y++) {
            headersHtmlArray[y].innerText = headersHtmlArray[y].innerText.concat(', $');
        }
    }
}

function setCurrencyRateEur() {
    let rateMultiplier = prompt('Enter the exchange multiplier for EUR', '41.5');
    if (rateMultiplier == null) {
        return;
    } else if (isNaN(parseFloat(rateMultiplier))) {
        alert('Input error.');
        return;
    } else {
        window.currency = 'eur';
        let currencyUsdButton = document.getElementById('currency-usd-button');
        let currencyEurButton = document.getElementById('currency-eur-button');
        let interactiveElements = document.getElementsByClassName("table-controls")[0];
        currencyUsdButton.setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.35;");
        currencyEurButton.setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.5; color: blueviolet;");
        interactiveElements.setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.5;");
        rateMultiplier = parseFloat(rateMultiplier);
        currencyEurButton.firstElementChild.innerText = '1 EUR = ' + rateMultiplier + ' UYU';
        let costsTableData = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        let costsHtmlArray = costsTableData.getElementsByClassName('numdata');
        let eurPriceString, currentItemCost;
        for (let i = 0; i < costsHtmlArray.length; i++) {
            currentItemCost = parseFloat(costsHtmlArray[i].innerText.replace(',', '.'));
            eurPriceString = (currentItemCost / rateMultiplier).toFixed(2);
            costsHtmlArray[i].innerText = eurPriceString;
        }
        let costsHeadersData = document.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0];
        let headersHtmlArray = costsHeadersData.getElementsByClassName('numdata');
        for (let y = 0; y < headersHtmlArray.length; y++) {
            headersHtmlArray[y].innerText = headersHtmlArray[y].innerText.concat(', €');
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that my code is terribly written, I basically have no coding skills beyond writing a VBA macro for Excel.
It works fine though, but I don't want to develop bad habits in building js applications.
Could you please point me in a good direction to rewrite this?

Comment: First tip: don't use `prompt`, instead use an `<input type="text">` field. Second tip: put all the `let element = document.getElementById(...)` calls outside of the functions, as the first thing in your code. It will make everything more readable. Third tip: put CSS in a `.css` file, and only use `addClass` and `removeClass` in your JS.